# "Failure to load viewstate" error unless debug=true

Tags: asp.net, debugging, web-config, runtime-error, viewstate

When a search page is called from a few specific pages on my site, the code fails with the following error in the function System.Web.UI.Control.LoadViewStateRecursive(Object savedState):

> MESSAGE: Failed to load viewstate.  The control tree into which
>   viewstate is being loaded must match the control tree that was used to
>   save viewstate during the previous request.  For example, when adding
>   controls dynamically, the controls added during a post-back must match
>   the type and position of the controls added during the initial
>   request.

However, if I add `debug="true"` to the following line in the web.config file, there is no error:

```
<compilation defaultLanguage="c#" batch="false" targetFramework="4.0">
```

Why does adding `debug="true"` fix the error? What is a different way to solve the problem?

Comment: Really strange, but be aware that any error during postback can generate this error http://forums.asp.net/t/1106625.aspx

Comment: How is the search page called from the other pages?  The error about loading view state means so the error is on a post back.  Are you posting from another page to your search page or does it happen after the post back on the search page when you perform your search?  Does this happen on a development machine or only on a deployed site?